# Is the line in bold grammatically correct?

Tags: grammar, grammaticality

> Meanwhile, the FTSE 100 hit a new record high last month. While rising interest rates and higher commodity prices hammered many stocks, they flattered the banks, miners and energy giants of London’s once-unfashionable stock exchange.
>
> **Even Britain’s sovereign-debt, or “gilt”, market has settled down.** Just months ago a disastrous budget by Kwasi Kwarteng, then chancellor of the exchequer, threatened it with catastrophe. But under Jeremy Hunt, Mr Kwarteng’s more competent and responsible successor, a repeat seems out of the question.
>
> — *Economist* [2 March 2023](https://www.economist.com/britain/2023/03/02/britains-stockmarket-has-languished-its-gilt-market-may-be-next)

What bothers me is that this line **Even Britain’s sovereign-debt, or “gilt”, market has settled down.** reads as incomplete to me. I would throw in a 'for' between Even and Britain to make it into "even for Britain's sovereign-debt, or “gilt”, market has settled down. Am I overthinking?

Comment: You are overthinking.

Comment: I take it that the gilt market has settled down. The commas are odd, though, as very *interrupty*.

Comment: Parentheses would be calmer; one can skip to the end. And double quotes for a nickname is overquoting, as you point out.

Answer (score 2):

Try reducing the sentence progressively:

*sovereign-debt, or gilt,*
in this part, *gilt* is in apposition with *sovereign-debt*, as an alternative or explanation. So we may simplify the sentence to:

*Even Britain’s sovereign-debt market has settled down.*
*Even* is an adverb qualifying *has*, making comparative reference to what has gone before. Hence, the simple form is:

*Britain’s sovereign-debt market has settled down.*
*sovereign-debt* is an adjective. Removing it gives the core sentence:

*Britain’s market has settled down.*

If you work this analysis in reverse, it does not justify the insertion of *for*.

Note: the use of *even* as adverb is described, for example, in:

> [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/even)
> even adverb (SURPRISE):
> used to show that something is surprising, unusual, unexpected, or extreme:
> *I don't even know where it is.
>
> Everyone I know likes the smell of bacon - even Mike does and he's a vegetarian.*

Comment: @JK2 thanks for spotting the typo. I have corrected  it.

Comment: If _even_ qualifies _has_, the adverb should belong to the predicate, but why does the meaning change when we move the adverb? _Britain’s sovereign-debt market has even settled down._

Comment: @JK2 I hope my extra note answers your point. There are more examples in the Cambridge entry. I have only quoted the first two.

Comment: I'm not disputing that OP's _even_ is an adverb. What I'm saying is that OP's _even_ is similar to the second Cambridge example, but is different from the first.